# Create new instance of Child class from Base class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, typescript

I want to create new instance of **Child** class from **Base** class method.

It's a little bit complicated, but i will try to explain.

Here's an example:

```js
class Base(){
    constructor(){}

    clone(){
        //Here i want to create new instance
    }
}

class Child extends Base(){}


var bar = new Child();
var cloned = bar.clone();

clone instanceof Child //should be true!
```

So. From this example i want to clone my `bar` instance, that should be instance of `Child`

Well. I'm trying following in `Bar.clone` method:

```
clone(){
    return new this.constructor()
}
```

...And this works in compiled code, but i have typescript error:

`error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

Any ideas how i can handle this?

Thank you. Hope this helps some1 :)

Comment: If anyone is still encountering this and looking for a solution that does not discard type information, the strategy posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45871004/131782) about returning `this` seems to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast to a generic object when cloning an unknown object.
The best way to do this is to use the `<any>` statement.

```
class Base {
    constructor() {

    }

    public clone() {
        return new (<any>this.constructor);
    }
}

class Child extends Base {

    test:string;

    constructor() {
        this.test = 'test string';
        super();
    }
}


var bar = new Child();
var cloned = bar.clone();

console.log(cloned instanceof Child); // returns 'true'
console.log(cloned.test); // returns 'test string'
```

Comment: Is it not possible to say that this.constructor derives from Base?

Comment: Doing it this way you lose Type information. The correct solution likely involves generics, though I haven't quite figured it out.